# Laravel array of object update failing for unique email

Tags: laravel-6

I am using Laravel 6.I have an API that sends an array of staff, some are existing objects that need to be updated and some are new objects that need to be created. The creation part works but update fails due to "DUPLICATE ENTRY for UNIQUE EMAIL".I am using a function in controller

```
    class AdminController extends Controller
    {
    public function userTransfer()
    {
    $caremanagementUserData = Admin::on('validated')->get();

    $caremanagementUserData->each(function($userData)
    {
        if(User::where('email', '=', $userData['email'])->exists()) {

            User::on('mysql')->where('id', '=',$userData['id'])->update([
                'username'     => $userData['username'],
                'email'        => $userData['email'],
                'password'     => $userData['password']
            ]);
        } else {
            User::on('mysql')->insert([
                'username'     => $userData['username'],
                'email'        => $userData['email'],
                'password'     => $userData['password']
            ]);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Help me about how to send email in the update array to solve the unique email error.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to get around the problem. Because email is unique and if email existence is being checked by

```
    if(User::where('email', '=', $userData['email'])->exists()) 
    {}
```

email update should be omitted from array of object, and if a new email is send it will be inserted as new data. It works for me !